# Preferred use cases for iBeacon on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-location, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am currently trying to get used to CoreBluetooth and iBeacon on iOS 7. While searching through the API, I noticed that there seem to be three ways of creating and using iBeacons, and I am not 100% sure what the differences are and when to use which. The ways I found are:

- A location-based approach using `CBPeripheralManager` and `CLLocationManager` with a `CLBeaconRegion`. This has the advantage that it gives me information about the proximity of the devices. But since this is a location-based approach it seems to me that I cannot transfer data with this, which is something I need.
- Using the Multipeer Connectivity Framework classes, `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`. This is very easy to set up, allows me to transfer arbitrary data but I get no information about the proximity of the two devices, which I need.
- I found an [example project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple where they use `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheral`. This allows me to transfer arbitrary data and get limited proximity information (I get the RSSI but no signal accuracy), but seems pretty complex since there are lots of callbacks and I have to take care of stuff like flow control myself.

So I guess my question is: Is there a preferred way? When to use which method? Can they be combined? For example, could I listen to other devices using the location-based approach and then connect to the device when it is nearby using the Multipeer Framework? If so, how could I make sure that I don't accidentally connect to the wrong device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iBeacon is for determining location - the idea is that the information about the detected iBeacon is cross-referenced to some other database, say via web services, to determine a physical location - say a branch or store location.  While an iBeacon can be another iOS device it may also be a dedicated, but very simple, [piece of hardware](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon/) so there is no ability to transfer data.

The CoreBluetooth framework is about discovery of services and small data transfers.  It supports both "well known" service types (such as a heart-rate monitor) and proprietary types.  Data ('Characteristics') can be both read and written and a subscription/notify model is used - for example notify when the heart-rate changes.

The Multipeer Connectivity Framework can use Bluetooth or WiFi to advertise and locate services and supports larger data transfers including streaming.

Which technique or techniques you use will depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So that means that methods 2 and 3 are not iBeacon-related at all? I thought so because they did not need any kind of pairing process in order to transmit data. I know that iBeacons can be practically any BTLE device, but is it possible to transfer data to non-iOS devices using methods 2 and 3?

Comment: I may add that I do not need to transmit lots of data - in fact, just a few bytes to make the device that is in range of an iBeacon know what website to visit would be enough. But I guess that isn't possible?

Comment: That is correct. iBeacon uses Bluetooth Low Energy capabilities, so it is related to the others but it is a specific use case. CoreBluetooth is Apples implementation of the GATT Bluetooth service so it is compatible with other vendors - for example an App that supports heart rate monitors should work with any monitor that implements the heart rate monitor profile. CoreBluetooth does require pairing if an attribute is flagged as requiring encryption but it is not mandatory as it is with the older Bluetooth standards and devices (e.g. Hands free device). MCF is Apple iOS specific

Comment: iBeacons are sometimes thought of as an equivalent to a QR code or NFC sticker in the Android world, but this is not the case. For an iBeacon to work there needs to be a specific app running in the phone that has registered for notification of a specific beacon UUID. Along with the UUID the beacon advertises two numbers. One number could represent a sub-brand (acme men's, acme kids, acme shoes) and the other could be a store id. The app could receive this information and launch the appropriate sub-branded web site and also pass the store id in the URL for example

Comment: So, an iBeacon can trigger a web site from a pre-programmed list of web sites but it can't advertise an arbitrary web site

Comment: alright, thank you unfortunately I cannot hardcode the URL (academic project... bla bla specific setup... I won't bore you with the details). But since it seems possible to transmit data using `CB` without pairing, I hope I can get something working with that

Comment: A minor detail, but it is not the hardware of physical iBeacon devices which prevents transmitting additional data, but rather that there is simply no provision for this in the "iBeacon" concept.  To date, everyone is using more flexible BTLE chips which were designed before the iBeacon scheme was announced, and which are capable of quite a variety of things depending on the firmware loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You first must decide if you want to use standard iBeacons. If so you cannot use Multipeer Connectivity because standard iBeacons do not support that.  Standard iBeacons are transmit only devices that do not allow you to directly do two way data transfer.

You also cannot use `CoreLocation` with `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheral` to see iBeacons because the APIs block access to the  iBeacon identifiers on iOS.  See my answer [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).

If you want to use standard iBeacons (allowing use of off the shelf hardware and utilities) you must use `CoreLocation` APIs.  This let's you do ranging easily but not two way data transfer.

Comment: thank you, the link was very helpful. Like I mentioned in my comment above, is it possible to detect and transmit data with non-iOS-BTLE devices using `CBCentralManager` or the multipeer connectivity framework?